# Using Direct Mount brakes on braze on frame

Tags: shimano, rim-brake, build

I've just purchased a frame with a single hole in the middle (of the forks and on the rear bit where the rear brakes mount), and a pair of direct mount rim brakes.

I was wondering if there was some sort of adapter that I could buy from Shimano / elsewhere to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is one. I found one image on Google that appears to look like it would adapt a standard frame/fork to take direct mount brakes, but I wasn't able to find a link to any manufacturer. There is an exceedingly brief discussion [in this forum post](https://weightweenies.starbike.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=156882).

Because direct mount rim brakes are a niche item, I wouldn't hold out much hope for an adaptor. In fact, the link is mainly sarcastic commentary.

Comment: Well, that's a big sad. I guess I'll just have to buy another set